# Progressbar is not going down python 3.4 tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to empty a progressbar that is full, simulating the behavior of a syringe but for some reason is not working.

With a button I call `mAspire`, which call sEmpty(), then sUp(), then sStop() and then sFull(), so it will create 2 empty progressbars, then fill it with the function ".step" then stop these progress bar and then create 2 full progressbars

With a button I call `mDispense`, which call sFull(), then sDown(), then sStop() and then sEmpty(), so it will create 2 Full progressbars, then empty them with the function ".step" then stop these progress bar and then create 2 empty progressbars

Why is not Working???????

Help

```
import time
import serial
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
try:
    import Tkinter
    import ttk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tkinter
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

mGui = Tk()
mGui.title("try bar")
mGui.geometry('1250x650+10+10')

BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                                 mode='determinate')
BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                                 mode='determinate')
BarVolSyringe1.place(x=952,y=238)
BarVolSyringe2.place(x=930,y=238)

dir = -10
dirr = +10
def sStop():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    BarVolSyringe1.stop()
    BarVolSyringe2.stop()

def mAspire():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    sEmpty()
    mGui.after(1000, sUp)
    mGui.after(10000, sStop)
    mGui.after(10010, sFull)

def sUp():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    BarVolSyringe1.step(dirr)
    BarVolSyringe2.step(dirr)
    mGui.after(10, sUp)

def mDispense():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    sFull()
    mGui.after(1000, sDown)
    mGui.after(9999, sStop)
    mGui.after(10000, sEmpty)

def sDown():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    BarVolSyringe1.step(dir)
    BarVolSyringe2.step(dir)
    mGui.after(10, sDown)

def sFull():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 100)
    BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 100)
    BarVolSyringe1.place(x=952,y=238)
    BarVolSyringe2.place(x=930,y=238)

def sEmpty():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 0)
    BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 0)
    BarVolSyringe1.place(x=952,y=238)
    BarVolSyringe2.place(x=930,y=238)

mButtonAs = Button(mGui, text = "Aspire", command = mAspire,
                   fg = 'Black').place(x=110,y=360)
mButtonDis = Button(mGui, text = "Dispense", command = mDispense,
                   fg = 'Black').place(x=160,y=360)
```

There are no python messages with errors, but when I run the function it just stays full and never empties the progressbar. Why this is not working?

Comment: In `sDown()` you should be getting an error about `BarVolSyringe1` being undefined. Try running your script from a command shell prompt.

Comment: try the code again, I have uploaded the whole code

Comment: Why are you recreating `BarVolSyringe1` and `BarVolSyringe2` in all those functions? Shouldn't they all be updating the global instances that were created near the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, in a simple way, take it an try it on python

```
import time
import serial
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
try:
  import Tkinter
  import ttk
except ImportError:
  import tkinter as Tkinter
  import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time
mGui = Tk()
mGui.title("GUI")
mGui.geometry('120x450+100+100')
BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 0)
BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 0)
BarVolSyringe1.place(x=52,y=38)
BarVolSyringe2.place(x=30,y=38)
SFg=0
SFd=0
SyringeSize = 1000
Sy = SyringeSize/100
SVV_1 = 500
def mAspire():
 global SFg,SFd, BarVolSyringe2,BarVolSyringe1
 if SVV_1<=SyringeSize:
  while 0<=SFg<SVV_1:
    SFg=SFg+1
    SFd=SFd+1
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    BarVolSyringe1.step(1/Sy)
    BarVolSyringe2.step(1/Sy)
    mGui.update()
    print (SFg)
  else:
    mGui.update()
    SFg=0
    print (SFd)
  if (SFd >= SyringeSize):
    BarVolSyringe1.stop()
    BarVolSyringe2.stop()
    BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 100)
    BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 100)
    BarVolSyringe1.place(x=52,y=38)
    BarVolSyringe2.place(x=30,y=38)
    SFg=SVV_1
 else:
  messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Please Select a valve")
mButtonAs = Button(mGui, text = "up", command = mAspire, fg = 'Black').place(x=10,y=60)

def dw():
  global SFg,SFd, BarVolSyringe2,BarVolSyringe1
  SFg=0
  while 0<=SFg<SVV_1:
    SFg=SFg+1
    SFd=SFd-1
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    BarVolSyringe1.step(-(1/Sy))
    BarVolSyringe2.step(-(1/Sy))
    mGui.update()
    print (SFg)
  else:
    mGui.update()
    SFg=0
    print (SFd)
  if (SFd == 0):
    BarVolSyringe1.stop()
    BarVolSyringe2.stop()
    BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 0)
    BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 0)
    BarVolSyringe1.place(x=52,y=38)
    BarVolSyringe2.place(x=30,y=38)

mButtonAs = Button(mGui, text = "dw", command = dw, fg = 'Black').place(x=10,y=90)
```

Answer (score 1):

`BarVolSyringe1` is undefined in `sDown`, it's a local variable in `mDispense`. Create bars outside the functions to be shared:

```
BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 100)
BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, mode='determinate', value = 100)

def mDispense():
    BarVolSyringe1.place(x=952,y=238)
    BarVolSyringe2.place(x=930,y=238)
    sDown()
    mGui.after(5100, sEmpty)  # Schedule sEmpty only once, not in each sDown call

def sDown():
    BarVolSyringe1.step(dir)
    mGui.after(100, sDown)

def sEmpty():
    BarVolSyringe1.step(-100)
    BarVolSyringe2.step(-100)
```

**Edit:**

You should not make assignments to `BarVolSyringe1` and `BarVolSyringe2` in your functions. They are global variables, and assigning a value with `BarVolSyringe1 = ...` doesn't rewrite a global variable, it just creates a local one with the same name, which shadows the global until the function ends. So the bars you created outside of the functions stay there and get updated with `sDown`, but you don't see this, because the bars created in `sFull` are displayed over them.

To solve this either:

- create variables globally and only use their accessor methods like `BarVolSyringe1.step`, `BarVolSyringe2.update`
- put `global` declaration before assigning to a global variable in a function:

```
def sEmpty():
    global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2
    BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, 
                                     mode='determinate', value = 0)
    BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, 
                                     mode='determinate', value = 0)
```

- make `BarVolSyringe1` and `BarVolSyringe2` internal to some mutable object, for example some `dict`, `list`, an instance of some class or `mGui`. Then you will be able to access and update them anywhere through that object.

```
mGui.BarVolSyringe1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, 
                                      mode='determinate', value = 100)
mGui.BarVolSyringe2 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, 
                                      mode='determinate', value = 100)
```

or

```
syringes = {
    'BarVolSyringe1': ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                                      mode='determinate', value = 100),
    'BarVolSyringe2': ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78, 
                                      mode='determinate', value = 100)
}

# Updating examples:
syringes['BarVolSyringe1'].step(dir)
syringes['BarVolSyringe1'] = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                                             mode='determinate', value = 100),
```

or

```
syringes = [
    ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                    mode='determinate', value = 100),
    ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                    mode='determinate', value = 100),
]

# Updating examples:
syringes[0].step(dir)
syringes[1] = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=78,
                              mode='determinate', value = 100),
```

Comment: still, is not working, the progressbar starts full and then pass to empty, but nothing in between, I mean the bar is NOT showing step by step how it is going down untill is time to call mEmpty

Comment: I am going to upload the code for you to see it, test it, just copy and paste PYTHON 3.4

Comment: ok, I am not really familiar with python, so why do I have to use ttk.progressbar, or mGui.BarVolSyringe1, and what is "mutable object"??, anyway, I have to create a new bar every time because: when I select a button in my program I have to update an image/picture (I have 30 images, so I put the image and then I use another button to call mAspire, then change image and call button mDispense) and then I have to put these progressbars in front of that imaage, so I have to create them every time, so I want to see the new progrss bars going down thats all

Comment: @JoseFernandoGomezDavila When you create a new one the old ones remain on the screen, but are covered with the new ones. And `sDown` changes the old ones but not the new.

Comment: I have to create a new bar every time because: when I select a button in my program I have to update an image/picture (I have 30 images, so I put the image and then I use another button to call mAspire, then change image and call button mDispense) and then I have to put these progressbars in front of that imaage, so I have to create them every time, so I want to see the new progrss bars going down thats all

Comment: Just use the first method, put `global BarVolSyringe1, BarVolSyringe2` at the start of every function where you assign to those variables.

Comment: look I just want to fill the progress bar when I press a button so I am using ".start(2)" and then leave it full so I am creating a new one totally full "ttk.progressbar(value = 100)", then when I press another button the progress bar should empty gradually then i use ".step(-1)", then I create a new progressbar totally empty "ttk.progressbar(value = 0)", I do not know a better method to do this, plase help because this one is not working

Answer (score -1):

Try this for sDown.

```
def sDown():
    BarVolSyringe1.step(dir)
    BarVolSyringe1.update ()  # Added this.
    mGui.after(1000, sDown)
    mGui.after(5100, sEmpty)
```

Comment: still, is not working, the progressbar starts full and then pass to empty, but nothing in between, I mean the bar is NOT showing step by step how it is going down untill is time to call mEmpty

Comment: I am going to upload the code for you to see it, test it, just copy and paste PYTHON 3.4

Comment: The call to update is not necessary, and actually subtly harmful. As a general rule you never need to call update.